# What is the alternative to @RunWith(JMock.class)?

Tags: java, jmock

We have moved to Java 1.7 and now Jmock.class is deprecated.  Is there an alternative?  Seems the website has been abandoned...

Comment: I'm not sure that moving to Java7 has resulted in the JMock runner being deprecated. Have you updated to a newer version of JMock itself?

Comment: I downgraded the jars and all is good.  Thanks for the tip...

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic.  The JMock website has been abandoned and this information is nowhere on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the `JUnitRuleMockery` rule.

```
public class TestSomething {
    @Rule
    public final JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

    @Mock
    private MyInterface interface;

    @Test
    public void testTheThing() {
        context.checking(new Expectations{{

         }});
        // etc.
    }
```

You'll need the jmock-junit4 dependency on your classpath...

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```